# Restlet toObject() fails on XML with special characters reserved for XML

Tags: java, xml, restlet

Is there any way to convert XML to Java object in Restlet toObject() with some configurations?

toObject from ServerResource works well and converts the XML into Java object if request XML does not contain any reserved special characters of XML e.g. '&'.
otherwise it fails with following exception.

```
org.restlet.resource.ResourceException: Unprocessable Entity (422) - The server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct but was unable to process the contained instructions
```

//Request XML,

```
<Contain>
    <Elem> Johnson & Johnson </Elem>
</Contain>
```

// Java code,

```
PVRequest req = toObject(representation, PVRequest.class);
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that you can preprocess the xml so that you replace all special characters with allowed alternatives (provided that you have access to the xml file)?

Comment: I have the XML access, but it does not help. Because once the toObject() happens with preprocessed xml then the java object will have the pre-processed values and then I have to run again some replace function.

I don't want to add more and more conversion functions. Restlet is having this serious defect I guess. It opens up the SQL injection issue if there is no solution to this.